# passing javascript to angularjs displays only the first value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to build copy and paste in angularjs by calling javascript **getelementby Id()** functions.

I have 3 rows in the database but each time I click on **CopyText** button only the First rows gets copied **(Eg. Title1)** . If I try to copy text on row 2 **(Eg. Title2)** , The first rows will be copied again.

Now I have decided to implement **angular.copy()** functions but it will display 
 values **undefined**. Below is the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <form>
    <br> post Title<br>


<input type="text"  id="post.title" ng-model="post.title">

<button  id='but_save{{$index}}' ng-click="myFunction_copy(post)">Copy text</button><br>
</form>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $parse) {

  $scope.posts = [
    {
      "pid" : "1",
      "title" : "title1"
    },
    {
      "pid" : "2",
      "title" : "title2"
    },
    {
      "pid" : "3",
      "title" : "title3"
    },
  ]



$scope.post = {}; 
$scope.myFunction_copy = function(post){
var copyText = document.getElementById("post.title");

//var copyText =angular.element(document.getElementById('post.title'));
  //var copyText = angular.copy("post.title"); 

alert(post.title);



  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}


});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` elements all have the same id: `post.title` (literally!). You'll want to use the dynamically retrieved post title, for which you must use double braces:

```
<input type="text"  id="{{post.title}}" ng-model="{{post.title}}">
```

In the same way, your JS code is retrieving the `input` element with the *literal* name `post.title`. You should remove the double quotes and do:

```
var copyText = document.getElementById(post.title);
```

Comment: it show error parse syntax. If I remove the double braces, the error will be gone but the issue remains

Comment: you are right, i have a typo error somewhere. its working now

Comment: Good to hear ;-)